# How do I show the source code of an S4 function in a package?

Tags: r, package, r-s4

I used the packages topGO in R to analyze gene enrichment with the following code:

```
sampleGOdata <- new("topGOdata", description = "Simple session", ontology = "BP",
                    allGenes = geneList, geneSel = topDiffGenes, nodeSize = 10, 
                    annot = annFUN.db, affyLib = affyLib)
resultFisher <- runTest(sampleGOdata, algorithm = "classic", statistic = "fisher")
allRes <- GenTable(sampleGOdata, classicFisher = resultFisher, orderBy = "fisher", 
                   ranksOf = "classicFisher",topNodes = 10)
```

I want to see and change the `RunTest` function and the `GenTable` function to change the `ResultTable`, but I don't know how to show the function. With the `getAnywhere("GenTable")` I do not get the hard code I want.

```
getAnywhere("GenTable")
```

> A single object matching ‘GenTable’ was found
>
> It was found in the following places
>
> ```
> package:topGO
>
> namespace:topGO
> ```
>
> with value
>
> ```
> function (object, ...)
> standardGeneric("GenTable")
> <environment: 0x16a30c10>
> attr(,"generic")
> [1] "GenTable"
> attr(,"generic")attr(,"package")
> [1] "topGO"
> attr(,"package")
> [1] "topGO"
> attr(,"group")
> list()
> attr(,"valueClass")
> character(0)
> attr(,"signature")
> [1] "object"
> attr(,"default")
> `NULL`
> attr(,"skeleton")
> function (object, ...)
> stop("invalid call in method dispatch to \"GenTable\" (no default method)",
> domain = NA)(object, ...)
> attr(,"class")
> [1] "standardGeneric"
> attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
> [1] "methods"
> ```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `getMethod()` and specify the signature. In your case, that could be eg :

```
getMethod("GenTable","topGOdata")
```

to show the GenTable method for topGOdata objects. In this case, there is only a method defined for topGOdata objects. In case there are methods with different signatures, `showMethods()` will tell you which ones. In your case :

```
showMethods("GenTable")
# Function: GenTable (package topGO)
# object="topGOdata"
```

You can get the code for the signature you want by specifying it in the `getMethod()` function.

Comment: In case the function (method) you're after is a non-visible function you need to use `getAnywhere()`. For example, I want to look for the source code for the method associated with the function summary() for a spatial probit model.  Then `methods(summary)` shows me all methods associated with the function summary. The method `summary.ProbitSpatial` is an non-visible method. Then `getAnywhere(summary.ProbitSpatial)` gives the source code. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but for the sake of completeness for future searchers, there's also a function called

```
selectMethod
```

that varies from getMethod in that you can use inheritance. This is how I found source for a generic function that has multiple signatures.

Comment: a more complete demonstration of how `selectMethod` works and differs from `getMethod` would be appreciated