# show source code for a function in a package in R

Tags: r, r-s4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: show source code of an S4 function in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937832/r-show-source-code-of-an-s4-function-in-a-package)

I downloaded a package (`GEOquery`) and was playing with some of the functions. One of them is called `Table`, which, to my understanding, is able to tabulate an `S4` dataset.

E.g.

```
> summary(GDS2853) # GDS2853 is a dataset I downloaded from NCBI 
Length  Class   Mode 
     1    GDS     S4
```

`getAnywhere(Table)` shows

```
> getAnywhere(Table)
A single object matching ‘Table’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:GEOquery
  namespace:GEOquery
with value

function (object) 
standardGeneric("Table")
<environment: 0x06ad5268>
attr(,"generic")
[1] "Table"
attr(,"generic")attr(,"package")
[1] "GEOquery"
attr(,"package")
[1] "GEOquery"
attr(,"group")
list()
attr(,"valueClass")
character(0)
attr(,"signature")
[1] "object"
attr(,"default")
`\001NULL\001`
attr(,"skeleton")
function (object) 
stop("invalid call in method dispatch to \"Table\" (no default method)", 
    domain = NA)(object)
attr(,"class")
[1] "standardGeneric"
attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
[1] "methods"
```

I'd like to learn the code of `Table` so that I could know how to tabulate a GDS dataset, as `data.frame` and `as.list` couldn't coerce an `S4` class - although I could tabulate GDS dataset by, for example,

```
GDS_table=Table(GDS2853)[1:20000,1:20] #GDS2853 contains 20 columns
and approx 17000 rows
```

I tried the `getMethods` as suggested in other posts but below is what I got

```
> getMethod("Table")
Error in getMethod("Table") : 
  No method found for function "Table" and signature
```

I also tried to specify the "where" by putting in `package=:GEOquery` but apparently `package` is an unused argument.

Wonder what I did wrong so as to fail to see the source code for `Table`.

Answer (score 9):

From the output you posted, it looks like `Table` is an S4 generic.

To view a list of its S4 methods, use `showMethods()`. To view a particular method, use `getMethod()`, passing in the 'signature' of the method you want along with the name of the function. (A 'signature' is a character vector composed of the class(es) of the argument(s) according to which the generic `Table` performs its method dispatch. i.e. if you will be doing `Table(GDS2853)`, the signature will likely be `class(GDS2835)`)

Here's an example that gets the code for an S4 method in the **sp** package:

```
library(sp)

showMethods("overlay")
# Function: overlay (package sp)
# x="SpatialGrid", y="SpatialPoints"
# x="SpatialGrid", y="SpatialPolygons"
# x="SpatialGridDataFrame", y="SpatialPoints"
# x="SpatialGridDataFrame", y="SpatialPolygons"
# x="SpatialPixels", y="SpatialPoints"
# x="SpatialPixelsDataFrame", y="SpatialPoints"
# x="SpatialPoints", y="SpatialPolygons"
# x="SpatialPointsDataFrame", y="SpatialPolygons"
# x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialGrid"
# x="SpatialPolygons", y="SpatialPoints"

getMethod("overlay", signature=c("SpatialGrid", "SpatialPoints"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I must confess I still don't understand exactly what the "signature" entails. The description from ?getMethod didn't help me much either. But I tried and found that, like Joshua mentioned, with signature="GEOData", getMethod did get me something to further follow up.

Comment: a side note- just noticed that (plus someone else's posting) both showMethods and getMethod seem to be about "method" - not so much about "function". As GDS download is mostly a S4 class, it seems that I would need a "method", not a "function" to manage the dataset. Is this correct?

Comment: S4 methods are function, just like S3 methods are functions. You might be able to better get your head around this if you start by looking at a few S3 methods. Try, for example, typing: `methods("print")`, and then pick a few familiar ones, and look at them -- perhaps `print.data.table` and `print.lm`. What makes those two functions "methods" is that they can both be invoked by typing `print(obj)`: *which* function gets used depends solely on the class of `obj`. (We say that they, along with the 100+ other functions returned by `methods("print")` are "print methods".) HTH.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, it would be:

```
getMethod("Table", "GEOData")
```

You may also be interested in how to get the help documentation for S4 methods, which has an equally unusual invocation required:

```
method?Table("GEOData")
```

Generally, with S4, you will need

- the function name
- the class (signature) of objects it is for

If you are lost as to the latter:

```
class(object)
```

will return the class, and you can also do:

```
showMethods("Table")
```

to show all currently available methods.  Alternatively, I find I often use:

```
findMethods("Table")
```

and the reason is the `findMethods` returns a list of all the methods for a particular function.  Classes can have long names and I find I mistype/miscapitalize them often so as a quick hack, `findMethods("functionname")` is handy.  Of course, it can also bite you for generic functions with many methods as the printed list may be quite long.

Comment: Nice tip about getting the docs for methods! Thanks.