# How to find source code of dbWriteTable for postgres connection?

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a theory that the function `RPostgreSQL::dbWritetable` converts `POSIXct`dates to character before writing them. I am trying to see the source code to confirm this, and despite looking at the following links I am unable to find it. In fact, I do not even know whether what I am looking at is an S3 or S4 method:

[show source code for function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782403/show-source-code-for-function-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

[How do I show the source code of an S4 function in a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937832/how-do-i-show-the-source-code-of-an-s4-function-in-a-package?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Firstly, I have the results of `RPostgreSQL::dbWriteTable`:

```
nonstandardGenericFunction for "dbWriteTable" defined from package "DBI"
  defined with value class: "logical"

function (conn, name, value, ...) 
{
    ans <- {
        standardGeneric("dbWriteTable")
    }
    .valueClassTest(ans, "logical", "dbWriteTable")
}
<environment: 0x00000000122305e8>
Methods may be defined for arguments: conn, name, value
Use  showMethods("dbWriteTable")  for currently available ones.
```

The next step seems straightfoward:

```
> showMethods("dbWriteTable")
Function: dbWriteTable (package DBI)
conn="PostgreSQLConnection", name="character", value="character"
conn="PostgreSQLConnection", name="character", value="data.frame"
```

This doesn't give me any clues on what to do further. Running `getAnwhere`:

```
> getAnywhere("dbWriteTable")
A single object matching ‘dbWriteTable’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:RPostgreSQL
  package:DBI
  namespace:DBI
with value

function (conn, name, value, ...) 
{
    ans <- {
        standardGeneric("dbWriteTable")
    }
    .valueClassTest(ans, "logical", "dbWriteTable")
}
<environment: 0x00000000122305e8>
attr(,"generic")
[1] "dbWriteTable"
attr(,"generic")attr(,"package")
[1] "DBI"
attr(,"package")
[1] "DBI"
attr(,"group")
list()
attr(,"valueClass")
[1] "logical"
attr(,"signature")
[1] "conn"  "name"  "value"
attr(,"default")
`\001NULL\001`
attr(,"skeleton")
(function (conn, name, value, ...) 
stop("invalid call in method dispatch to 'dbWriteTable' (no default method)", 
    domain = NA))(conn, name, value, ...)
attr(,"class")
[1] "nonstandardGenericFunction"
attr(,"class")attr(,"package")
[1] "methods"
```

But as there is no `object = ...` output I have no idea how to use [getMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937832/how-do-i-show-the-source-code-of-an-s4-function-in-a-package?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: `getMethod("dbWriteTable",signature = c("PostgreSQLConnection", "character", "data.frame"))` [from another link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679941/show-source-code-for-a-function-in-a-package-in-r)

Comment: thanks, that is it!

Comment: Embarassingly I did not read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19226817/2109289 properly. The relevant part is the bit that starts with: "There are also methods with more complex signatures for each method, for example"